# Catching all invalid memory usage?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual C++, sometimes when a resource has been destructed it can still be "accessed" via anything pointing to that memory location (albeit very unreliably/stably). Is there a way to have VC++ return an exception/message/etc. which would warn against this kind of unstable use?

For example:

```
int *c = new int(5);
delete c;
std::cout << *c << std::endl; // will execute, however the value is likely to be invalid
```

On a slightly related question, do Linux systems experience this same problem, or would this result in a segfault?

Comment: makes me think whether there exist such kind of reference pointer model which is not reference-counted but "master/slave" of sort, i.e. deleting one reference invalidates all others?

Comment: @davka : Read about `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use raw pointers? Using `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` or standard containers or boost's ptr containters will really reduce your `new`/`delete` problems. Also revisit your design and try to minimize spiderwebs of pointers between objects as much as possible. Use `weak_ptr` when you can.

But to answer your question more directly: There is no sure way. Accessing a deleted item is undefined behavior and as such anything is game. Your best bet is the MS debug malloc or using say valgrind or another memory checker. Heap and memory problems are hard to debug.

EDIT: It's undefined behavior so Linux systems again may or may not get a segfault.

EDIT2: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f7sy2e9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx you define `_DEBUG` in conjunction with using a debug CRT library to enable the debug heap functions.

I didn't initially mention Purify because of its cost, but I've had quite good luck with it in the past.

Comment: How do I do that (use debug malloc)? I've set my build to debug but it'll continue to use the regular malloc.

Comment: For Windows, the equivalent to Valgrind would be [Rational Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/)

Answer (score 0):

```
int *c = new int(5);
delete c;
c = null;  //add this
```

Comment: that works for this example, but it's possible that the resource is still pointed to somewhere else. I'm just wondering if there was some automated check to help in the development process

Comment: This wouldn't work even for this example. Dereferencing a deleted pointer invokes undefined-behavior even if you do `c=NULL`.

Comment: You have to do stuff manually in C++. You have to take care of wild pointers. If there are more pointers pointing to the same memory location, when you delete the contents, you should make them all null.

Answer (score 0):

Third party tools are available: for Visual C++, there's Purify (but it's expensive), and perhaps some other tools.  (Linux has Valgrind, but I don't think it's available for Windows.)  Other than that, design is your best friend.  C++ doesn't require you to use that many pointers, and there use should be part of your design.